# Filtering by date and keywords using beautiful soup on RSS Feeds

Tags: python-3.x, filter, beautifulsoup

I managed to scrape off RSS feeds from a site using beautiful soup 4 however not able to filter by today's date, and by keyword for the title and link of certain news to be displayed.

Is there a way I could set a question for input, e.g. 
enter date to view news:
enter preferred keywords:

My current code as follow

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import requests
import csv

source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.channelnewsasia.com/rssfeeds/8396082').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
print(soup.get_text())
```

The output returns a whole list of news and links, but just hope to only see by preferred date and those that meet the keywords such as 'COVID'. Appreciate anyone who could help in this!

Answer (score 0):

This example will print articles that contains word `covid` published at latest 2 days ago:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import namedtuple
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

article = namedtuple('article', 'title desc pubdate')

url = 'https://www.channelnewsasia.com/rssfeeds/8396082'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'lxml')

articles = []
for title, desc, pubdate in zip(soup.select('item > title'),
                               soup.select('item > description'),
                               soup.select('item > pubdate')):
    d = datetime.strptime(pubdate.get_text(strip=True), '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
    articles.append(article(title.get_text(strip=True), desc.get_text(strip=True), d))

# example:
# print articles with keyword COVID published 2 days ago:

kw = 'covid'
now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
two_days_ago = timedelta(days=2)

for a in articles:
    if kw not in a.title.lower() and kw not in a.desc.lower():
        continue

    if now - a.pubdate > two_days_ago:
        continue

    print(a.title)
    print(a.desc)
    print(a.pubdate)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
IMM, Clementi Mall, Tanglin Mall and four other locations visited by COVID-19 cases
SINGAPORE: IMM, Clementi Mall, Woodlands Mart, Woodlands North Plaza, Yuhua Village Market and Food Centre, Tanglin Mall and a Housing Development Board (HDB) block at 82 Marine Parade Central were on Monday (Jun 8) added to the list of public places visited by COVID-19 cases during their ...
2020-06-08 23:28:48+08:00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SDP calls for period between Writ of Election and Nomination Day to be extended to 10 days
SINGAPORE: The Singapore Democratic Party (SDP) on Monday (Jun 8) called for the period between the issue of the Writ of Election to Nomination Day to be doubled, in a response to the Election Department's (ELD) release of contingency plans for holding a General Election during the COVID-19 ...
2020-06-08 21:50:38+08:00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
What are the COVID-19 safety measures for Polling Day? Here’s what voters need to know
SINGAPORE: The Elections Department (ELD) has issued contingency plans on how the next General Election (GE) will be held amid the COVID-19 outbreak.

Safety measures include dedicated time-bands for seniors to vote, setting up more polling stations and having voters wear gloves before entering ...
2020-06-08 20:20:38+08:00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

... and so on.
```